# Azure Content Moderator SDK Delete Term From List Problem

Tags: c#, azure, api, sdk, azure-cognitive-services

I am using content moderator on my api but one method does not work. Every other method will work correctly but delete term method does not work. Can you help me for this method?

Packages and tools are;

-Visual Studio 2019 Community

-.net core 5.0 web api

-Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.ContentModerator 2.0 nuget version

-PC Windows 10 last version

My method:
**await _contentModeratorClient.ListManagementTerm.DeleteTermWithHttpMessagesAsync(_termListId, text, AzureCognitiveConsts.TurkeyCode);**

I tried every way to delete term on exist list but it did not work. Also status code is 204 with no content. Other delete methods(deletelist etc) work fine. Why this delete method creates problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Syntax to Delete a Term from the list**

```
public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Microsoft.Rest.HttpOperationResponse<string>> DeleteTermWithHttpMessagesAsync (string listId, string term, string language, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Collections.Generic.List<string>> customHeaders = default, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
```

For reference please follow this [Microsoft Document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cognitiveservices.contentmoderator.ilistmanagementterm.deletetermwithhttpmessagesasync?view=azure-dotnet)

Comment: Yes I am using this method in my project. If I create a Turkish(**tur parameter** ) term list and then delete a term with this method, method does not work. But English language (**eng parameter** ) works well. I think that delete problem is about langugae. Please you can try this delete method with Turkish language. Thank you @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT